# Working with images in Scala

Tags: scala, image-processing, png

I am generating large PNG files from a Scala program.  Currently, I am doing it the same way I would do it in java.  I am creating a new `BufferedImage` and setting each pixel to the correct color.  This works fine, but I am wondering if there are any good libraries for working with images in Scala?  I am looking for something like Ruby's [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) library.

Comment: Not Scala specific: You can do a few nice things with the Java Media APIs: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/2D/

Comment: Did you find anything good for Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe **JMagick**? Take a look [here](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html), it's a native interface between ImageMagick and Java exactly like RMagick..

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize this existed.  Still, I am interested if something more idiomatic exists for Scala.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage (Disclaimer: I am the author)

This is an open source Scala image library that essentially wraps java.awt Image operations in a nicer API as well as providing easy methods for operations like fitting to a given size, etc.